# How do i link 2 object files to form a binary file

Tags: ld

I have tried using ld to link 2 .o files together with this,

> ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin kernel.o ks.o

but it produce an error saying

> ld: cannot open linker script file link.ld: No such file or directory

Is there anything wrong with my commands or do i have to create a path or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the "linker script" `link.ld`. Google "linker script" for docs.